# jquery ui slider pips change percentage steps

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI slider pips however because some of the labels were overlapping I'd like to change the percentage steps used.

So for example I have four steps, `min:0, max:3`. The plugin divides the steps proportionally (in css, `left: 0%, 33%, 66%, 100%`)

but I'd like to change these to allow the labels to be shown without any overlap, but retain four steps (e.g. `left:0%, 20%, 45%, 90%`).

What I've done is

```
$j( "span.ui-slider-pip.ui-slider-pip-label.ui-slider-pip-1" ).css('left','20%');
```

and so on for the other percentages. This moves the labels as I'd like them, but now the actual slider handle doesn't match up when I slide it since it's using the original percentages. I'm looking in the plugin code but can't see how I could affect it in this particular case.

How could I change the jQuery to move the slider to my custom percentages?

Comment: You could use a smaller step (eg. 5%) and prevent the slider from landing on any but the four values wanted. Alternatively extend the widget and change the step calculation, though I'm not sure how simple that will or will not be. Could you make a MCVE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible without re-writing the `_trimAlignValue()` method in the slider plugin core...

```
$.ui.slider.prototype._trimAlignValue = function() {
    /* your logic here */
};
```

Here's the source code for reference:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/slider.js#L518-L537

---

I did a very quick play around, and you should get a kind-of desired effect with this:

```
$.ui.slider.prototype._trimAlignValue = function(v) { 
    if( v < 0.3 ) {
        return parseFloat( 0 );
    } else if( v < 1 ) {
        return parseFloat( 0.6 );
    } else if( v < 2 ) {
        return parseFloat( 1.35 );
    } else {
        return parseFloat( 2.7 );
    }
}
```

So long as you keep your slider's `max` at **3**, and `min` at **0**. But you may also have to re-align your `pips` to match this trim-aligned value. Also you will need to convert the `ui.value` outputs to whatever you want, but that should be simple.

Best, Simey.